# Can I bypass battery protector for battery level indicator?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging, indicator

I have 2 series Li-ion batteries which are connected to a 2s battery protector. I want to indicate battery level **only when a button is pressed**. The problem starts when I  **measure battery level while charging**. If I connect the indicator across the **P+** and **P-** it will assume the adapter's voltage as battery voltage thus **always** give fully charged result. That's why I want to connect the battery level indicator across **B+** and **B-** as below:

[image: new connection]

**Is it something I should avoid or is it okay to bypass the protector?**

The indicator:

[image: indicator]

The protector:

[image: protector]

The charger adapter is 9V/1A

Comment: I would put a few ohm in series just in case.

Comment: In case of a short? Well yeah, I can put a fuse for example, if anything else is okay.

Comment: Sure, but a resistor is cheaper :-)

Comment: A Li-Ion battery is NEVER charged directly from a power supply. It is charged from a charging circuit that limits the charging current which reduces the charging voltage. When the charging battery reaches its maximum of 4.2V per cell it is still charging. When the 2s discharging battery voltage drops to 6V it is just about dead and should have its load disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

You'd lose the safety that your battery protection circuitry is supposed to give you against shorting. So, don't.

Your li-ion charger needs to keep track of the charge state itself, so it knows the charging state, which is effectively impossible to read just from the voltage over the battery during charging, anyways, since that always incorporates temperature changes and time-dependent behaviour.

Comment: There are only 5 Leds on the indicator thus the resolution is really low. So slight wrong measurements via voltage won't matter I guess. Also, can you give me a better way to measure the battery level? Thanks.

Comment: "impossible to read" does not mean "more accurate than 20%", it does mean "useless for estimating the charge state". I gave you a better way: ask the charge controller. A 5-segment display seems pretty good. Getting any more precise is going to be relatively hard without counting ampereseconds.

Comment: How can I extract the battery level information from the charge controller? Should I tap into some pads of the ICs?

Comment: I don't know the charge controller, so I can't tell you that. You bought the charge controller, so you should have its datasheet!